# Retrieve date time doing http post request

Tags: javascript, forms, express, http-post, httprequest

I have a table and a form that retrieves datas and sends them to a database. After submitting the form, a new table rows is created with the datas just submitted.

I'd like to add a field for each rows with the date and time of the submit.

If I click on submit button, I do a http post request.

Is it possible to save the time and date of the submit?
I'm using mongoose for the db and express for the router.

```
import Router from 'express';
const router = Router();

router.post('/', isAuthorized(), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let fruit = new Fruits(req.body);
        await fruit.save();
        res.json(fruit);
    } catch (err) { res.status(503).send(err); }        
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the timestamps of the POST request on the server-side, with your mongoose models.

In your `mongoose` `Fruits` `Schema`, you can add a `timestamps` field, with the default set to `new Date()`. So something like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const FruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ... other Fruit properties...
    timestamps: { type: Date, default: () => new Date() }
});
```

Or instead, you can utilize `mongoose`'s built in `timestamps`, by passing in a second object to your `Schema`, like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const FruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ... Fruit properties ...
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

This will automatically add `createdAt` and `updatedAt` to your newly created `Fruits` documents.

Comment: The first solution is perfect for me, the second one could be better but I feel good with the first one. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can get date and time using the `Date` object.

pass the below code into the code wherever you want to save. (like MongoDB)

```
let date_ob = new Date();
```

Read more about [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)